# How to change tag classes based on tag's text color or dark mode activated/deactivated?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a Dark Mode switch. Imported from https://github.com/coliff/dark-mode-switch

It works really good but I had 2 problems.

Firstly, the NavBar Brand text wasn't changing.

Easily fixed with

```css
[data-theme="dark"] .teste {
    color: white;
}
```

Now, I have another problem. When the website is on light mode, I have the "border" class enabled to surround the navbar.
But when I change it to DarkMode, it's ugly and looks better without the border.

To fix this, I tried to use the checkbox state to enable or disable the border class with javascript but after hours, no success.

I then tried to use CSS but no luck too.

I then thought about changing html tag's classes with CSS but that's not possible.

How can I fix this?

[image][image]

Thanks

Comment: `[data-theme="dark"] .classname { border-color: transparent;}` or any color which you want

Comment: @Vitorinofernandes didn't work. Maybe I should've mentioned I'm using the class border from BootStrap. Thanks

Comment: have you tired with `!important` and the class name should be the one who has the `border`

Comment: @Vitorinofernandes ma man. ma savior. That worked like a charm! Thanks a lot dude!

Comment: your welcome happy to help you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[data-theme="dark"] .classname { 
    border-color: transparent !important;
}
```

Just replace the `.classname` with your class

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {
  padding: 25px;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.dark-mode {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Toggle Dark/Light Mode</h2>
<p>Click the button to toggle between dark and light mode for this page.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Toggle dark mode</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
   var element = document.body;
   element.classList.toggle("dark-mode");
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```